# MSSQL RESTORE DATABASE Taking 10 times longer on AWS EC2 than On-Prem VM after Lift and Shift Migration

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, database-restore

Scenario:

My company's IT departments are in the middle of a major migration from on-prem VM Ware server hosting to AWS based server hosting.

An on-prem server running Windows 2016 DataCenter and SQL Server 2016 was replicated and migrated from on-premise to an AWS EC2. The server is 1:1, Lift & Shift from the on-premise instance.

This server is a "test/simulation" box that is used by our account management team to preform "what-if" analysis prior to hitting production with account configuration changes, for this reason the databases on this box need to be regularly refreshed at the account managers discretion.

The Data teams step a simple backup and restore jobs within the SQL Agent that restores the given database from a network available share location that hosts the most recent .bak file. Runs a few scripts to make the system non-production and brings the database online.

```
USE TestSIM1

BEGIN TRY 

IF EXISTS (SELECT EnvironmentLockedThru
            FROM [dbo].[GlobalSettings] gs 
            WHERE EnvironmentLockedThru IS NOT NULL 
                AND EnvironmentLockedThru >= GETDATE())
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'Environment is locked'
        RAISERROR ('Environment is locked', -- Message text.  
        16, -- Severity.  
        1 -- State.  
        );   
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN
        --PRINT 'Environment is unlocked or Lock has expired.'
        USE Master
        ALTER DATABASE [TestSIM1] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
        RESTORE DATABASE [TestSIM1] FROM  DISK = N'\\Storage22\SQL\Sim\ProdSvr.DBName.Mirror.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'DBName' TO N'D:\Data\TestSIM1.mdf',  MOVE N'DBName_log' TO N'E:\Logs\TestSIM1_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5
        ALTER DATABASE [TestSIM1] SET MULTI_USER
    END

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  
  
    SELECT   
    @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  
  
    -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error  
    -- information about the original error that caused  
    -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.  
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.  
    @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.  
    @ErrorState -- State.  
    );  
END CATCH;
```

This takes anywhere from 45-60 minutes to restore the FULL backup to the Test server on a given day on premise.

***After completing the migration of the server from on-prem to the AWS EC2 version of the server, it is now taking upwards of 10 hours to complete the restore.***

[image: Screenshot of Restore progress]

I am hoping someone might have an explanation for this behavior and a possible resolution for this.

EC2 Specs:
8 Core
32 GB RAM
<Will update the exact EC2, class when my team provides it back to me.>

SQL Server:
Processes: Set to Automatic Affinity for all Processers
Memory: 24 GB allocated

Comment: Some specs would be useful.  Depending on the size of the EC2 you may be running into CPU throttling.

Comment: Or I/O throttling. If you use RDS instead of manually managing EC2, it has point in time recovery built-in.

Comment: Or bandwidth issues. `a network available share location` where is that? Obviously not on the AWS VM. Another VM? Unlike your server room/data center, AWS networks are shared by all VMs and machines on a rack/pod/whatever

Comment: Added the specs for the EC2 and the SQL Server.

Comment: @SQLJax what VM tier? This affects not just the available CPU and RAM but *bandwidth* as well. If you try to restore over the network, this matters

Comment: So to answer questions:
@Jordanm : We are not using RDS yet for this, but it's an option I want to look into. This was quite literally a pick up and move scenario, and was done in haste.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : The share was in our on-premise storage array. Same network but not in AWS.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos VM tier or EC2 tier?

Comment: Look at the cloudwatch metrics for the instance to see if its maxing CPU or I/O. You didn't post the specs on the I/O for the volume attached to the instance.

Comment: @JordanM I need to get them from the AWS team, unfortunately, I am not in front of those as I work with the DB team.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: lift and shift is generally not going to save you money, it will more likely cost more. The whole point of cloud is to downsize at the same time by cutting away the fat. What are the specs for the IO you have given to the EC2 instance?

Comment: So it's really looking like this is an I/O concern. My IT group is telling me that the connection from our on-prem site and the AWS site is completely saturated with the migration efforts and pulling the backup from the on prem server storage location may be the key issue. I am transferring a backup directly to the AWS EC2 server and trying the restore again.

As for the L&S migration costing more, I agree, and I have to say I did have a more elegant plan of attack to migration in place, until we were rushed into a data center migration in 6 weeks.

Comment: I will update again after I have had a chance to retry the RESTORE action from the local backup

Comment: UPDATE: After running the backup from a local .bak file I got the restore down to 1.5 hours which is closer to normal. Pulling the backup from the AWS SQL AG node took nearly 3 hours to complete however. I  have my IT Team watching the cloudwatch metrics was we are doing the restores. Thank you for point me in the right direction